# How to get all the values of a variable inside a for loop when that variable is called outside the loop? (without using list.append ( ))

Tags: python, mysql, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to retrieve some information from a website. I used a for loop to get all the elements of that website that fulfill a criteria.

However, when I call the function outside the for loop, I am only getting the last item retrieved by the for loop.

I know I can create an empty list outside  the loop and append all the items. The problem with this is that I am inserting this information into MySQL using PyMySQL and  MySQL does not take in a list.

I know I can also transform a list into a string using " ".join(list) The problem with this is that MySQL takes this new object and sends it to one single cell in the database.

```
def getRestaurantLink(bs):   
    listLinks = [] 
    restGrid = bs.find_all ("ul", {"class": "lemon--ul__373c0__1_cxs 
    undefined list__373c0__2G8oH"}) 
    for i in restGrid:     
        link = i.find_all("a", {"href": re.compile ("/biz/.*")}) 
        for l in link:        
            if "target" in l.attrs and "name" in l.attrs and "rel" in 
            l.attrs: 
                listLinks.append (l.attrs["href"]) 
    for link in listLinks[0::3]:   
        links = ("https://www.yelp.com"+str(link))
        print (links)

html_page = requests.get("https://www.yelp.com/search? 
cflt=restaurants&find_loc=Hunts+Point%2C+Bronx%2C+NY+10474")
bs = BeautifulSoup (html_page.text, "html.parser")
getRestaurantLink(bs)
```

Comment: Try moving `listLinks = []` outside the function.

Comment: Are you aware that `for link in listLinks[0::3]` gets the first link, skips the second and third, gets the fourth link, skips the fifth and sixth, etc?  If that is only printing one link, then `listLinks` must contain three or fewer total links.

Comment: @Hatt How would that help?  The problem is that the list contains fewer items than expected.  Changing where the list is declared won't help that.

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks for the input. Yes, I am aware that  listLinks[0::3] gets the first link, skips the second and third, gets the fourth link, skips the fifth and sixth, etc. The reason why I am doing this is because every time the loop runs, listLinks  is receiving 3 identical links.

Comment: Then as I said, if the loop only prints one link, the list must contain three or fewer total links.  Are you expecting more than that?

Comment: Yes, I am because listLinks is a list of lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about the loading bit but this will return you the correct number of links as a list you can later loop.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_restaurant_links(url):  
    base = 'https://www.yelp.com'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    links = [base + i['href'] for i in soup.select('h3 [href^="/biz"]')]
    return links

some_list = get_restaurant_links('https://www.yelp.com/search?%20cflt=restaurants&find_loc=Hunts+Point%2C+Bronx%2C+NY+10474')
```